# Trouble finding kernel of a linear transformation $T_g: C^1[0, 1] \rightarrow C[0, 1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T_g: C^1[0, 1] \rightarrow C[0, 1]$ be the linear transformation
> $$T_g(f) = (fg)'$$
> Find the null space of $T_g$.

I'm having trouble formulating a correct answer to this problem. It is straightforward to note that $T_g(f) = 0 \iff (fg)' = 0$ and by the rules of differentiation this is true iff $f'g + g'f = 0$. Now it might be observed that

\begin{align*}
    &(f'g)(x) + (g'f)(x) &= 0 \\
    \iff&f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x) &= 0 \\
    \iff&\int f'(x)g(x) ~dx + \int g'(x)f(x) ~dx &= \int 0 ~dx \\
    \iff &f(x)g(x) - \int g'(x)f(x) ~dx + \int g'(x)f(x) ~dx &= C \\
    \iff&f(x)g(x) &= C
\end{align*}

where $C \in \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary constant. (Notice that from the third to the fourth line we used integration by parts.)

**I :** I am unsure of whether this result is correct. I'm quite new to linear algebra and I'm not confident on how valid my integration approach is.

**II :** Even if it is correct, the result $fg = c$    for $c$ a constant depends both on $f$ and on $g$. However, the kernel is dependent on the domain of $T_g$, whose elements are mapped onto the vector $f$. In other words, it seems dubious to define the kernel as

\begin{equation*}
    kern(T_g) = \Big\{f \in C^1[0, 1] : f = c_1, g = c_2 \mid c_i \in \mathbb{R}\Big\}
\end{equation*}

since $g$ is not a variable.

I'm sure I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $g$ ? Based on the question, it seems that $g$ is a fixed function and the linear operator $T$ is defined based on $g.$ Are you sure that $g$ is not known ?

Comment: Also, $f$ and $g$ need not both be identically constant functions. You could have for example, $f$ be identically $0$ and $g$ be any $C^1([0,1])$ function.  Or you could also have both nonconstant functions such as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$ and $g(x)=x-2$ for example.

Comment: @VivekKaushik Certainly. Seems like the only possibility is that either $f$ is $0$ or $f = 1/g$ (provided $g \neq 0$)...

Comment: $f = x/g$ for any $x$, actually...

Comment: If $f=x/g,$ then $fg=x$ assuming $g$ does not vanish, and $(fg)'=1 \ne 0.$ So $f$ is not in the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I : I am unsure of whether this result is correct. I'm quite new to linear algebra and I'm not confident on how valid my integration approach is.

You have the right idea, but I think you're thinking a little too hard as well. My thought process would have been like:

- "We need $(fg)' = 0$."
- "Well, derivatives of constants are zero."
- "Hence, $f$ needs to be such that $fg$ is a constant."

No real need for detailed calculations to make that realization.

> **II :** Even if it is correct, the result $fg = c$    for $c$ a constant depends both on $f$ and on $g$. However, the kernel is dependent on the domain of $T$, whose elements are mapped onto the vector $f$. In other words, it seems dubious to define the kernel as
>
> \begin{equation*}
>     kern(T) = \Big\{f \in C^1[0, 1] : f = c_1, g = c_2 \mid c_i \in \mathbb{R}\Big\}
>  \end{equation*}
>
> since $g$ is not a variable.

While the result depends, in some sense, on $g$, I think the original question is ill-framed. Notice that the domain of $T$ is $C^1[0,1]$, not $C^1[0,1] \times C^1[0,1]$. This is meant to indicate that $f$ is your variable, not $f$ **and** $g$. This is, in part, why the notation $T_g$ was used, but that should have been maintained throughout the problem statement.

In other words, treat $g$ as a fixed and given function; what must $f$ be so that $(fg)' = 0$? That is, no matter how $g$ is defined (so long as it is differentiable, obviously), how can you define $f$ so that $fg=c$ for a constant $c$?

Comment: Thanks, this was quite clear. It seems to be the case (as mentioned in the comments to the OP) that either $f = 0$ or $f = 1/g$ make up the null space.

Comment: Not quite; try $f=2/g$ as an example. Really, the null space is comprised of all $f=c/g$ for some scalar $c$.